# How can i spilt a string of sorts 10.1.1 and get each number as different column in a select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did this

```
select version,SUBSTRING(version,1,CHARINDEX('.', version) - 1) A,
SUBSTRING(version,CHARINDEX('.', version) + 1, CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(VERSION))-1)    B,
RIGHT(version,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(VERSION))-1)    C
from dbo.product
where version like '%.%'
```

But if the string , version is something like 10.2 i need the output as

**Sample output :**

```
 **Version    A       b      c**
 1  10.2.1    10       2      1
 2 10.2      10       2      null
 3 10        10       null   null
 4 null      null     null   null
```

Comment: please post the sample data what output do you need????

Comment: Can't you code this logic in your calling code? It would be much more readable / maintainable.

Comment: so if the data comes as 10.2 then 10 in one column and 2 in another column..is that you want ???

Comment: @Vakh  No! it has to be a inline cosmetic changes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select version, 
case
    when version not like '%.%' then version
    else substring(version,1,charindex('.',version)-1)
end as 'FirstPart',
case
    when version not like '%.%' then null
    when charindex('.',version) <= len(version)-charindex('.', reverse(version)) then substring(version, charindex('.',version)+1,charindex('.', reverse(version))-1)
    else substring(version, 2 + len(version)-charindex('.', reverse(version)), len (version))
end as 'SecondPart',
case
    when version not like '%.%' then null
    when charindex('.',version) <= len(version)-charindex('.', reverse(version)) then substring(version, 2 + len(version)-charindex('.', reverse(version)), len (version))
else null
end as 'ThirdPart'
from dbo.product
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RKEVE88087)

After writing and testing, I would still urge you to check if this can be done at the UI level.

Comment: @Mickey Don't understand why your edit got rejected, but  I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE ([version] VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES ('10.2.1');
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES ('10.2');
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES ('10');
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES (NULL);
SELECT
    [version],
    CASE WHEN [version] LIKE '%.%' THEN LEFT([version], CHARINDEX('.', [version]) - 1) ELSE [version] END AS A,
    CASE WHEN [version] LIKE '%.%' THEN SUBSTRING([version], CHARINDEX('.', [version]) + 1, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([version])) - 1) ELSE NULL END AS B,
    CASE WHEN [version] LIKE '%.%.%' THEN RIGHT([version], CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([version])) - 1) END AS C
FROM 
    @Product;
```

Results:

```
version A       B       C
10.2.1  10      2       1
10.2    10      2       NULL
10      10      NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (id varchar(10))
insert into @t (id) values ('10.2')

select SUBSTRING(id,1,CHARINDEX('.',id)-1),RIGHT(id,LEN(id)-CHARINDEX('.',id)) from @t
```

based on output you have asked we should follow this approach !!

OR required OUTPUT

```
declare @t table (id varchar(10))
insert into @t (id) values ('10.2.1')
insert into @t (id) values ('10.2.2')
insert into @t (id) values ('10.2')
insert into @t (id) values (NULL)

select id,
CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTRING(ID,1,CHARINDEX('.',ID)-1)END AS 'A',
CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE parsename(replace(ID, '.', '.'), 1)END AS 'B',
CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN NULLIF(ID, 'NULL') ELSE  SUBSTRING(ID,CHARINDEX('.',id)+3,LEN(ID))END AS 'C' from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

t --> table1

id --> Version

```
select id,SUBSTRING(id,1,CHARINDEX('.', id) - 1) A,
SUBSTRING(id,CHARINDEX('.', id) + 1,
case when CHARINDEX('.',id,CHARINDEX('.', id)+1) > 0 then 
(len(id) - CHARINDEX('.',id,CHARINDEX('.', id) + 1))
else
(LEN(id)- CHARINDEX('.', id)) end ) B,
SUBSTRING(id,CHARINDEX('.',id,CHARINDEX('.', id)+1)+1,
case when CHARINDEX('.',id,CHARINDEX('.', id,
CHARINDEX('.',id,CHARINDEX('.', id)))+1) > 0 then
(LEN(id)- CHARINDEX('.',id,CHARINDEX('.', id))) else
null end ) C
from t where id like '%.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help everyone,

But i ended up doing this! Hope , this might help someone as well

```
SELECT VERSION,
SUBSTRING(VERSION,1,CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('.', VERSION) - 1)<0 THEN len(VERSION) ELSE   CHARINDEX('.', VERSION) - 1  END) A,
CASE 
WHEN CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(VERSION))-1 <0 THEN NULL
WHEN LEN(VERSION)- LEN(REPLACE(VERSION,'.',''))=1 THEN   RIGHT(version,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(VERSION))-1)
ELSE SUBSTRING(version,CHARINDEX('.', version) + 1, 
LEN(VERSION)-CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(VERSION))-LEN(SUBSTRING(VERSION,1,CASE WHEN     (CHARINDEX('.', VERSION) - 1)<0 THEN 2 ELSE CHARINDEX('.', VERSION) - 1  END))-1)  

END B,
CASE 
WHEN LEN(VERSION)- LEN(REPLACE(VERSION,'.',''))=2 THEN     RIGHT(version,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(VERSION))-1)
ELSE NULL
END C

FROM (select '1000.2.2' as version)a
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Something like this

```
;WITH Split_Names (Version, xmlname)
AS
(
 SELECT Version,
       CONVERT(XML,'<Versions><ver>' + REPLACE(Version,'.', '</ver><ver>') + '</ver></Versions>') AS xmlname
 FROM Table1
)

 SELECT Version,      
 xmlname.value('/Versions[1]/ver[1]','varchar(100)') AS A,    
 xmlname.value('/Versions[1]/ver[2]','varchar(100)') AS B,
 xmlname.value('/Versions[1]/ver[3]','varchar(100)') AS C
 FROM Split_Names
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd740/1)**

Output:

---

```
VERSION     A       B      C
10.2.1      10      2      1
10.2        10      2      (null)
10          10      (null) (null)
(null)      (null)  (null) (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write try following query to split each version by (.) DOT Delimiter.

```
SELECT 
                `version`,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 1) AS A,
                SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 2), LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 1) ) + 2, LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 1) )) AS B,
                SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 3), LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 2) ) + 2, LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 2) )) AS C,
                SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 4), LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 3) ) + 2, LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`version`, '.', 3) )) AS D

FROM dbo.product
WHERE `version` LIKE '%.%';
```

It will be helpful.